# PHP move_uploaded_file Rename file

Tags: php

I know that `move_uploaded_file()` sets the name of the uploaded file and sets the destination also. I have this:

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the    file in a variable
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/profiles/'.$_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ; // Moving Uploaded file`
```

I have tried explode `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` but I don't get to change the name of my uploaded file to my POST variable `$newfile=$_POST["something"];`

Thank you in advance

Comment: didn't get your question properly. do you want to use the posted variable as filename? `$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/profiles/'.$_POST["something"];`?

Comment: Yes, exactly.. thanks, but the problema was the extension of the file. Now I figured it out. I did `$ext = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);`

Comment: @LaloOceja, Please surf internet before posting common question, the answer of this question can found at many places

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using

//File name

```
$file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file_name = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file_name);
```

// get extension

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

// change name

```
$imagename = $file_name . time() . "." . $ext;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the entire upload path with the file name in $targetpath variable.
In you code

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$newfile=$_POST["something"]; //any name sample.jpg
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/profiles/'.$newfile;
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;
```

Now the uploaded file name is sample.jpg
I think this will helpful for you.